Properties are saved properly in Core Data but it is not getting fetched?
I have a Core Data entity called UserList which contains identifier of currently logged in user. UserList has on to many relationship with entities like Users, UserLinks, UserAllowedSellRoles and UserAllowedBuyRoles .
I have a save method to save different arrays like users ,userLinks, sellRoles and buyRoles in core data .
The data is getting saved correctly. But when I fetch the data associated with that particular user in UserList , only the sellRoles, userLinks and buyRoles have data .
This is the save method ;
static func saveUsers(_ id: String, userDetails: [JSON?],userLinks: [JSON?], userBuyRoles: [JSON?], userSellRoles: [JSON?],completion:@escaping ( Bool) -> ()) {
    let context = CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UserList")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier == '\(id)'")
    
    do {
        var usersArray = [Users]()
        
        for obj in userDetails {
            let entityUsers = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Users", in: context)
            let usersObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entityUsers!, insertInto: context) as! Users
            usersObj.id = Int16(obj?["id"].intValue ?? 0)
            usersObj.firstName = obj?["first_name"].stringValue
            usersObj.lastName = obj?["last_name"].stringValue
            //other properties related to user
            usersArray.append(usersObj)
        }
        
        var userLinksArray = [UserLinks]()
        
        for objUserLinks in userLinks {
            let entityUserLinks = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserLinks", in: context)
            let userLinksObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entityUserLinks!, insertInto: context) as! UserLinks
            userLinksObj.url = objUserLinks?["url"].stringValue
            //other properties related to user links
            
            userLinksArray.append(userLinksObj)
        }
        
        var userAllowedSellRolesArray = [UserAllowedSellRoles]()
        
        for objSellRoles in userSellRoles {
            let entityUsers = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserAllowedSellRoles", in: context)
            let userAllowedSellRolesObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entityUsers!, insertInto: context) as! UserAllowedSellRoles
            //properties related to user sell roles
            
            userAllowedSellRolesArray.append(userAllowedSellRolesObj)
            
        }
        
        var userAllowedBuyRolesArray = [UserAllowedBuyRoles]()
        
        for objBuyRoles in userBuyRoles {
            let entityUserAllowedBuyRoles = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserAllowedBuyRoles", in: context)
            let userAllowedBuyRolesObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entityUserAllowedBuyRoles!, insertInto: context) as! UserAllowedBuyRoles
            //properties related to buy roles
        }
        
        let results = try context.fetch(request) as? [NSManagedObject]
        if results?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
            let userListObj = results?.first  as! UserList
            userListObj.identifier = id
            userListObj.user = NSSet(array: usersArray)
            userListObj.userLinks = NSSet(array:userLinksArray)
            userListObj.buyRoles = NSSet(array:userAllowedBuyRolesArray)
            userListObj.sellRoles = NSSet(array:userAllowedSellRolesArray)
            
            try context.save()
            print("Stored Data Successfully")
            completion(true)
            
        }else {
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserList", in: context)
            let userListObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! UserList
            userListObj.identifier = id
            userListObj.user = NSSet(array: usersArray)
            
            userListObj.userLinks = NSSet(array:userLinksArray)
            userListObj.buyRoles = NSSet(array:userAllowedBuyRolesArray)
            userListObj.sellRoles = NSSet(array:userAllowedSellRolesArray)
            try context.save()
            print("Stored Data Successfully")
            completion(true)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Fetch Failed: \(error)")
        completion(false)
    }
}

This is the fetch method ;
 static func getUsersInfo(_ completion:@escaping (NSArray,NSArray,NSArray ) -> ()) {
        let context = CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
        print("Fetching Data")
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UserList")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            guard let results = try context.fetch(request) as? [NSManagedObject] else { return}
            
            for obj in results {
              let userObject = obj as? UserList
                let users =  (userObject!.user! as NSSet).allObjects as NSArray
                let buyRoles = (userObject!.buyRoles! as NSSet).allObjects as NSArray
                let sellRoles = (userObject!.sellRoles! as NSSet).allObjects as NSArray
                
                print("users \(users)")
                print("buyRoles \(buyRoles)")
                print("sellRoles \(sellRoles)")
                completion(users,buyRoles,sellRoles)
            }
           
        } catch {
            print("Fetch Failed: \(error)")
        }
    } 

I have tried inspecting the sqlite DB and users data is getting saved properly. I have checked the entity inspector too and all the relationships are set up correctly .
Note : I did not write this code and this core data model was added as a new version recently . I had added a new constraint "id" for users which previous models didn't have. Is it because of any issues in data migration ?

”only the sellRoles, userLinks and buyRoles have data .”, those are the only properties being returned in the code so the fetch method seems to work. That said, it’s a really weird solution and if you want to access all relationships why not return the fetch array directly?

@JoakimDanielson I am trying to return users from Users entity . But it's returning 0 . But data is in the store .
